# Github - import an unversioned project from local filesystem

Tags: git

I have a folder in my local filesystem called "projecteuler". I would like to import the source files in this folder into a remote Github repository. How can I do this? My local folder "projecteuler" is not on any kind of version control system.

Comment: Does the remote repository already exist? And you want to add new files to this repository?

Comment: Yes. It exists but it's empty. I just created it a few minutes ago. Is there a way to import local code when you create a new remote repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the remote repo.
2. Copy the unversioned files into the clone's directory tree.
3. Add the files with `git add -A`.
4. Commit the changes.

Answer (score 3):

In your local project, do:

```
git init
git remote add upstream repository_address (repository_address is e.g. git@github.com:facebook/hhvm.git)
```

and now, you can add your files to via `git add`, commit the changes and push it into your git repository

Answer (score 0):

One step is missed in previous answers (mrosiu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866370/449413) and mipadi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866326/449413))

The missed step is to push local commits to remote repositories hosted in Internet or network somewhere. In this case Github. So additional to them below command has to be executed:-

```
$ git push <repository>
```

If mrosiu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28866370/449413) is followed for solution then the remote repository would be ***upstream*** so above command will be :-

```
$ git push upstream
```

[here](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/) more details